# Maven searching for an old version of Javax.Mail dependency (1.4.3) though I have the latest version of it (1.6.1) and throwing ClasNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail, classnotfoundexception, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to write a piece of code in the Cucumber testRunner class, to send the test result report through Email after execution, but I have come across this issue that I have not been able to solve. I added the dependency for the Javax.Mail libraries (version 1.6.1) and wrote the following methods inside testRunner,

```
@AfterClass
public static void teardown() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {       
    HTML_TestExecutionReportParser testExecutionStatusParser = new HTML_TestExecutionReportParser();
    sendTestExecutionReportEmail(testExecutionStatusParser.isAssertionFailureFound());    

}

public static void sendTestExecutionReportEmail(boolean testExecutionStatus) throws IOException {
    String mailSubject = null;
    String mailBody = null;     
    if (testExecutionStatus) {
        mailSubject = "Sub";
        mailBody = "body";
        sendEmail(mailSubject,mailBody);            
    }
    else {
        mailSubject = "Sub";
        mailBody = "body";          
        sendEmail(mailSubject,mailBody);
    }

}

public static void sendEmail(String mailSubject, String mailBody) throws IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    PropertyFileLoader propFileLoader = new PropertyFileLoader();
    prop = propFileLoader.loadPropertyFile("PropertyFiles", "EmailConfiguration.properties");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", prop.getProperty("SMTPHostName"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", prop.getProperty("SMTPPort"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", prop.getProperty("SMTPHostName"));
    final String EmailP = prop.getProperty("SMTPP");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "10000");
    final String User = prop.getProperty("SMTPU");
    Configurations config = new Configurations();
    String reportFolderPath = "TestExecutionReports";
    String reportName = "report.html";

    try {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(User, EmailP);
            }
        });

        InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress("email", "name");
        InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress("email", "name");
        session.getProviders();
        session.setDebug(true);
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(fromAddress);
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
        msg.setSubject(mailSubject);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textBodyPart.setText(mailBody);
        MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String attachmentName = config.getResourcePath(reportFolderPath) + reportName;
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachmentName);
        attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        attachmentBodyPart.setFileName("Report.html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
        msg.setContent(multipart);      
        Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

There are no errors shown in the code, but when I run it, it throws the following error in the console,

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun 
Microsystems, Inc.,1.4.3]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

Initially when I wrote the code, although I had the dependency with the latest version mentioned in the POM.xml file, I couldn't find any Javax.mail jar file under the Maven Dependencies, but the code wasn't showing any error. Later I somehow managed to properly install the Javax.mail libraries (version 1.6.1) through Maven, but when I run the tests, the above exception kept throwing and from the first line of the above console output, I am assuming that Maven is looking for an older version of Javax.mail libraries and since it is not available, it is throwing the classNotFound exception. But I am not sure how to point Maven to the latest Javax.mail libraries that is available under Maven Dependencies.

Any help is much appreciated...!

Edit: The mvn dependency:tree log as below,

```
 RestAssured:APITesting:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson- 
annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar:3.0.7:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- io.rest-assured:json-path:jar:3.0.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:2.4.12:test
[INFO] |  |  \- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:jar:3.0.7:test
[INFO] |  \- io.rest-assured:xml-path:jar:3.0.7:test
[INFO] |     \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.12:test
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] +- io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:jar:3.0.3:test
[INFO] |  \- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.6:test
[INFO] |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:test
[INFO] |     +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |     +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.2:test
[INFO] |     +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:test
[INFO] |     |  |  +- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |     |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:test
[INFO] |     +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:test
[INFO] |     \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:test
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-java:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |  \- info.cukes:cucumber-core:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-html:jar:0.2.3:test
[INFO] |     +- info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:jar:1.0.5:test
[INFO] |     \- info.cukes:gherkin:jar:2.12.2:test
[INFO] +- info.cukes:cucumber-junit:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.5.1:test
[INFO] +- com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.aventstack:extentreports:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.javafaker:javafaker:jar:0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.mifmif:generex:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

Comment: Post the `mvn dependency:tree` log.

Comment: what is your cucumber junit jar version?

Comment: In your pom.xml dependency jars, if any one of the jar has this javax.mail version 1.4.3 as a dependency, then you need to exclude this version jar.

Comment: @user2249207 - Yes, there was a javax.mail artifact as part of aonther dependency and lexicore helped me find it. The issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude `javax.mail:mailapi` from `io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

The problem is that your `pom.xml` effectively includes two Java Mail API artifacts: `javax.mail:mailapi` and `javax.mail:javax.mail-api`. Technically these are two different artifacts therefor including `javax.mail-api` with specific version does not override the version of `mailapi`.

Anyway `mailapi` seems to be the invalid artifact, probably deployed by someone by mistake.

You might also want to contact developers of [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) and let them know that they use the invalid `mailapi` artifact.

Comment: I've filed and [issue](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/issues/258) in [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, your solution solved the issue I was facing and this exception is no longer thrown. Thanks again..! :)

Comment: I tried up-voting already, but it says the vote of those with less than 15 reputation is recorded but do not change the public view. I will surely up-vote as soon as I gain those 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

On you IDLE for example in the case of IntelliJ. Re-import your maven project dependencies.

You can achieve this by clicking on Project Structure- > pom.xml > right click > Maven > Re-import.

This should re-import all your dependencies. Make sure as you said, you have the correct version mentioned in your pom.xml before you re-import.